# How to manage memory in TObjectDictionary in Delphi

Tags: dictionary, delphi

I want to kn ow how to manage correctly the memory when I have a TObjectDictionary in Delphi.

I want to create one ObjectDictionary of TShapes to paint circles in an Timage, but the position and the number of the circles changes every cicle.

I don't want to have memory leaks. In the on closeform I will do FShapes.Free, but I'm not sure if everytime I do FShapes.Clear what happens with memory.

I've read that I have to do it on the OnValueNotify, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
private
FShapes: TObjectDictionary<Integer, TShape>;

procedure TFRemote_Layout.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FShapes := TObjectDictionary<Integer, TShape>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
  FShapes.OnValueNotify := VNotify;
end;

procedure TFRemote_Layout.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FShapes.Free;
end;

procedure TFRemote_Layout.InsertShape(i, x, y: Integer);
var
  AShape: TShape;
begin
  try
    AShape := TShape.Create(nil);
    AShape.Top := x;
    AShape.Left := y;
    FShapes.Add(i, AShape);
  finally
    //Free AShape??
  end;
end;

procedure TFRemote_Layout.ClearDictionary();
begin
  FShapes.Clear; //This clear frees all the memory for the next cycle?
end;


//I was reading in embarcadero something like this, but not sure 
procedure TFRemote_Layout.VNotify(Sender: TObject; const Item: TShape; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
 Item.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I know that this works with .free but not sure if it also work with .clear

Comment: I think that's true, but when in doubt, if you want to test something like this, just make a simple class that shows a message in its destructor. Put an instance or two in an object dictionary, call clear, delete, free etc, and just see what happens. To my knowledge the event is just there so you can respond to items being added or removed, in case you want to update a UI in response, for instance.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for your quick answer, sometimes I have problems with memory managment. And good tip to test this type of issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing a [`TObjectDictionary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectDictionary) (by calling [`Clear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Clear) method) removes all the items from the collection. Ownership given in the constructor parameter then specifies whether the keys and/or the values will be released when the items are removed.

In your case having values owned, calling [`Clear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Clear) releases all the contained `TShape` objects with no need for any additional notification listener (for the [`OnValueNotify`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.OnValueNotify) event).

Comment: P.S. don't get confused by what the documentation of the [Clear](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Clear) method says, *"Clear does not free the items as they are removed."*. That applies to `TDictionary`, not to `TObjectDictionary` owning keys or values (which makes the essential difference between `TDictionary` and `TObjectDictionary`).